# Cleaning Up A Config File

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write this PS script but if someone beats me to the punch I'm sure they will get free karma.

Anyway here is what I want to take a file setup like this

```
foo.bar=Some random text is stored here
foo.bar=Lazy maintainers make me angry
bar.foo=Hello World!
bar.foo=Hello World!
```

The main goal is to remove any duplicated entries, which I have several of . . .  This seems easy enough with

```
Get-Content c:\list.txt | Select-Object -Unique
```

But I would also like to store any conflicts that have the same key identifiers into a separate file for so I can review which ones I should keep.

I'm still a PS novice and haven't found a good way to do this yet.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Group-Object` to group together items with the same key.  Then look for groups with more than one element in them (indicating duplicate entries).  Finally, print those out to a file somewhere:

```
# raw content
$lines = Get-Content C:\data.txt

# package each line into a little object with properties Key and Val
$data = $lines |%{ $key,$val = $_.Split('='); new-object psobject -prop @{Key = $key; Val = $val} }

# group the objects by key, only keep groups with more than 1 element
$duplicates = $data | group Key |?{$_.Count -gt 1}

# print out each key and the different values it has been given
$duplicates |%{ "--- [$($_.Name)] ---"; $_.Group | select -expand Val }
```

Result:

```
--- [foo.bar] ---
Some random text is stored here
Lazy maintainers make me angry
--- [bar.foo] ---
Hello World!
Hello World!
```

You can pipe that to `Out-File` if you want to store in a log.

Comment: Thanks, 400 odd lines of garbage was thrown out today because of you ^.^